# Trim decimal places before ceil

Tags: php

I have a problem with a ceil of a number.
The number is calculated like this. (The actual values comes from other places, this is just to show what is happening. The values in the example are correct to what's happening in the application)

```
$price = 400;
$multiPlierA = 1;
$multiPlierB = 1.1; 
ceil($price * $multiPlierA * $multiPlierB);
```

which should give me 440. But since $price * $multiPlierA * $multiPlierB ends up being 440.00000000000006 it will of course ceil it to 441. That little floating 6 at the end comes from lovely complementary php magic.

Is there a simple way to get get php to just do this calculation using the first two decimals? I want to trim this off before ceiling 440.00[000000000006....]

Comment: You can use number format before ceiling. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use number format before ceiling. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
$price = 400;
$multiPlierA = 1;
$multiPlierB = 1.1;
$result = number_format($price * $multiPlierA * $multiPlierB, 2, '.', '');
ceil($result);
```